# Why use FillChar to initialize an Integer

Tags: delphi, initialization, integer

Is there any special reason one would initialize a Delphi Integer variable using FillChar, rather than just assigning it an initial value? I've come across code like the following. It's not in a speed sensitive loop or anything. Using FIllChar here, especially immediately following a more conventional assignment of another variable, seems pointlessly obtuse. So what am I missing?

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  MyNum: Integer;
  MyPos: Integer;
begin
  MyNum:= 0;
  FillChar (MyPos, SizeOf (MyPos), 0);
  [...]
```

Comment: We can only guess, but I suspect you're looking at a bit left behind by a confused developer. Maybe he thought this would be extra zero-y.

Comment: The `FillChar` is intended rather for initializing structures (like arrays or records) not for a single value variable. So for better readability use just a simple value assignment like your `MyNum := 0;`.

Comment: @Ernest plus 1 for using the non-word zero-y

Comment: I second @TLama. "Extra zero-y" may be the high point of my day!

Comment: My guess - the author was not sure will `MyPos` var finally be of Integer type, and used a most general zeroing. Also possible that he was kidding :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Fillchar is used in this cases when you need to zero array or variable length data.
In example that you write I guess that developer think that MyPos can change it's type in future (maybe it will be record? or it was record?).